# How do I run an arbitrary test command on a Hosted agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

I would like to test that a command I'm crafting will work fine on a Hosted Agent with my DevOps Build Pipeline. The command could be quite complex or as trivial as `tsc --version`, for example.

How do I do it without modifying my `build-pipeline-definition.yaml` or rerunning the Build Pipeline?

Can I ssh/remote into the Agent and play around there? Or is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

> How do I do it without modifying my build-pipeline-definition.yaml or rerunning the Build Pipeline?

At the moment, [you don't](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1764). The way to test builds is to modify the build, run a build, and iterate if it's still not working.

> Can I ssh/remote into the Agent and play around there?

No. If you need access to an agent, install and configure a private agent on a machine you control.

Comment: That's too limiting *sigh*. Thanks for sharing the information

Comment: Just install the agent locally on your development pc. That way you get a faster feedback loop.