# How do I preinstall certain tools onto a Hosted Agent?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-hosted-agent

By default, the Hosted Agent I'm working with is not supporting `yarn` command but only `npm`. Sad, right?

Of course, I could have a step in my build pipeline that downloads and installs `yarn` via `scoop` or `choco[latey]` on each run, but I really don't like the idea of the build increase time for something that should be available to me out of the box.

So how do I preinstall the tools I need upfront?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55271108/azure-devops-how-do-i-run-an-arbitrary-test-command-on-a-hosted-agent

Comment: The tools installed on the hosted images is documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-image-generation).  From what I can tell both the VS2017 and Ubuntu16.04 images both currently have Yarn 1.13.0.

Answer (score 2):

You do not necessarily need to use a private agent -- you can run your builds in a prebuilt container. This way you can have control over a hosted agent.

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: tests
    image: my/container:tests

jobs:
  - job: run_tests
    container: tests
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'
    steps:
    # actual build
    ...
```

Comment: This is a muchly much better solution, yes!

Comment: all the steps will run inside the container (I'm not sure about built-in steps, how that would work. I only use script steps). code will get mounted inside the container as well

Comment: This will only work for Linux and Windows hosted agents. Other OS'es like MacOS don't support container jobs

Comment: This does not answer the question... why is this the most upvoted answer?

Comment: because it allows author to progress? suggest a better answer if you think it exists

Answer (score 0):

> Of course, I could have a step in my build pipeline that downloads and installs yarn via scoop or choco[latey] on each run, but I really don't like the idea of the build increase time for something that should be available to me out of the box.

This is the correct approach to install something on a build agent. If the increased time is a problem for you you could consider installing an agent on a machine of yours. But even if you use a private agent the approach to have some the installation done as a step of a build would be the correct approach

Comment: "to have some the installation done as a step of a build would be the correct approach" is very arguable at best. If I want to have `yarn` command available I need to run `scoop` or `choco` command to install it. Neither of those tools is available either, so I need to install them too. I may or may not want to orchestrate my tools as a part of the pipeline -- that's totally a preference thing. And I personally would prefer the toolset to be described side by side with the pipeline definition but NOT INSIDE it.

Comment: Just a small detail: choco is available on the hosted agents.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko hosted vs2017 has choco as well as yarn installed

Comment: @D.J.  I'll try them out. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You don't. The hosted agent is fresh every time. There is nothing you can do to cache things on it.

If that's a requirement, you should install a private agent on a machine you control.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I should indeed consider having a private agent instead...